# Set null when JSON Object doesn't have a key for value

Tags: java, android

I have an object which needs 4 parameters to set the values from a `JSONObject`. But, when I call `get(String name)` from `JSONObject` it has 3 values, so that throws a `JSONException`. Here is an example:

```
"JSON":{
    "aaa":"111",
    "bbb":"111",
    "ddd":"111"
}
```

How can set `null` for a value if the JSON key is non-existant.. not using GSON

Comment: Just set the key of that object to an empty string perhaps?

Comment: i can't set it. i'm just a receiver for create object for value of JSON and send it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

```
if (jsonObject.has("aaa") {
    this.aaa = jsonObject.getString("aaa");
}
```

Comment: `String test;
if (jsonObject.has("test") {
    this.test= jsonObject.getString("test");
}
else {
test = ""; 
}
`
that ok ? @Christian